# How to print custom sequence of tag using jackson databind lib in java?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

I am using Jackson XML annotation to serialize/deserialize xml output of my spring boot APIs. This API is meant to provide legacy support. Because of that, it's required to have the exact same response structure as a new API as well. I encountered a peculiar situation for which I could not find any solution. I tried customSerilizer but that also doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I need to **serialize** `A` and `B` tags into pairs without any parent tags. The existing XML serilizes data in this format.

```
<Item>
  <SNO>22656565</SNO>
  <Weight>0.0</Weight>
  <A>data1</A>
  <B>foo1</B>
  <A>data2</A>
  <A>data3</A>
  <B>foo3</B>
  <A>data4</A>
  <A>data5</A>
  <A>data6</A>
  <B>foo6</B>
</Item>
```

The java pojo look like this:

```
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Item")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"SNO", "Weight", "A", "B"})
public class Item {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SNO")
    private String sNo;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Weight")
    private Float weight;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> aList;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "B")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> bList;
}
```

Note: through a CustomSerializer I was able to read this data but serilization cannot be done. Whatever I try at the end all of `A` and `B` tags are grouped after serialization.

Could you please help in finding any solution to serialize this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `aList` has sizeA elements and `bList` has sizeB elements, which sequence of `A` and `B` tags should be produced in the XML?

Comment: Or maybe both lists have the same size, but in your example, `bList` has 3 null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to serialize your `Item` object with the alternate `A` and `B` tags in your xml file with a custom serializer, so if you use the provided `Item` class you can directly add a [`JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation over your class and it will work fine with the constraint of the same size of the two not null lists like you have specified:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ItemSerializer.class) //<-- here the new annotation
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Item")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"SNO", "Weight", "A", "B"})
public class Item {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SNO")
    private String sNo;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Weight")
    private Float weight;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> aList;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "B")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> bList;
}
```

So you can define a new class extending the [`StdSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html) providing the alternate writing of `A` and `B` tags for your lists:

```
public class ItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {

    public ItemSerializer() {
        super(Item.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Item value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("SNO", value.getSNo());
        jgen.writeNumberField("Weight", value.getWeight());
        List<String> aList = value.getAList();
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); ++i) {
            jgen.writeStringField("A", aList.get(i));
            jgen.writeStringField("B", value.getBList().get(i));
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

The expected result will be produced like below:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.setSNo("22656565");
item.setWeight(0.0f);
List<String> aList = List.of("data1", "data2", "data3");
item.setAList(aList);
List<String> bList = List.of("foo1", "foo2", "foo3");
item.setBList(bList);
String s = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(item);
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
<Item>
  <SNO>22656565</SNO>
  <Weight>0.0</Weight>
  <A>data1</A>
  <B>foo1</B>
  <A>data2</A>
  <B>foo2</B>
  <A>data3</A>
  <B>foo3</B>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 3):

With the following XML file:

```xml
<Item>
  <SNO>22656565</SNO>
  <Weight>0.0</Weight>
  <A>data1</A>
  <B>foo1</B>
  <A>data2</A>
  <A>data3</A>
  <B>foo3</B>
  <A>data4</A>
  <A>data5</A>
  <A>data6</A>
  <B>foo6</B>
</Item>
```

I tried this:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.*;

public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        Item item = mapper.readValue(new File("Item.xml"), Item.class);
        System.out.println(item.aList);
        System.out.println(item.bList);
    }

    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Item")
    public static class Item
    {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SNO")
        private String sNo;
        
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Weight")
        private Float weight;
        
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        private List<String> aList;
        
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "B")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        private List<String> bList;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[data4, data5, data6]
[foo6]
```

The result is not correct. That's because tags `A` and `B` are out of order in the XML. It seems to be a limitation
or bug of Jackson.

Here is a working solution based on [XStream](https://x-stream.github.io/) instead of Jackson:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver;

class Test2
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.allowTypes(new Class[]{Item.class});
        xstream.processAnnotations(new Class[]{Item.class});
        Item item = (Item)xstream.fromXML(new File("Item.xml"));
        System.out.println(item.aList);
        System.out.println(item.bList);
    }

    @XStreamAlias("Item")
    public static class Item
    {
        @XStreamAlias("SNO")
        private String sNo;

        @XStreamAlias("Weight")
        private Float weight;

        @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="A")
        private List<String> aList;

        @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="B")
        private List<String> bList;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6]
[foo1, foo3, foo6]
```

Comment: Thanks @Oliver for your answer, Unfortunately I couldn't change the xml dependencies as there are many classes with Jackson annotations. 

My primary need is to send this data out to user, I was able to serialize it using string regex but deserialization is still a problem. Have raised this issue at Jackson git repo.